# WooCommerce API Rest - 403 Error OAuth 1.0 HTTP

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce, localhost

I'm coming to you today because i'm blocked on 403 error since 3 days. I've got a Woocommerce Website on my localhost and I can not connect my POSTMAN agent to test the Rest Api.

I've saved my consumer key and consumer secret in a Oauth 1.0 in Postman but when I call /wp-json/wc/v3/products to just list all products, i've got a 403 error status with "Désolé, vous ne pouvez pas lister les ressources." and code "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view".

In parameters panel of woocommerce plugin, I can see the last connection of my API Key at the same time and i've configure it to call and write with calls.

I don't know how to resolve the problems so if anybody can help me

Thanks!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpT3E.png)

Comment: API request you're making is being authenticated but lacks the necessary permissions to view the resources (in this case, the products). So check your permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you give me the right way ! I had need to creat api key in woocommerce plugin interface. Have a good day !